# Pandas Merge Dataframes Sequentially on Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have 2 dataframe:

DF1:

**Col1** | **Col2** | **Col3**

**XCN000370/17-18C** | **XCN0003711718C** | **0003971718**

DF2

**Col1** | **Col2** | **Col3**

**XCN0003711718C** | **XCN0003711718C** | **0003971718**

I want them to merge like this:

- First Match Col1 (DF1) and Col1 (DF2)
- In Remaining Unmatched, Match Col1 (DF1) with Col2 (DF2)
- In remaining Unmatched, Match Col1 (DF1) with Col3 (DF2)

Now repeat this by exchanging DF1 and DF2 with remaining unmatched

- In Remaining Unmatched Match Col1 (DF2) and Col1 (DF1)
- In Remaining Unmatched, Match Col1 (DF2) with Col2 (DF1)
- In remaining Unmatched, Match Col1 (DF2) with Col3 (DF1)

Any ideas?

Comment: What’s the over all goal? As in what do you want your output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is one line code to do this. So follow the steps.

1) First, create a list:
`dfs = []`

2) Merge for each condition on dataframe:
`dfs.append(pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='col1',right_on='col1',how='outer')).dropna()`
`dfs.append(pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='col1',right_on='col2',how='outer')).dropna()`
`dfs.append(pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='col1',right_on='col3',how='outer')).dropna()`

^ repeat

3) Now concatenate them:
`pd.concat(dfs)`